# Split a group of n people into m balanced subgroups based on age and gender

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, grouping

I am looking for an algorithm to divide a group of n people into m balanced subgroups. In the same subgroup there must be the same number of people for each year of birth and, at the same time, each age group in each subgroup must have the same ratio of males to females. I also want to be able to create a shuffle function that randomly swaps out some people but always keeps the subgroups balanced. What algorithm should I use? Thanks!

Example:

**Input**

| Name | Birth year | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1980 | M |
| B | 1980 | M |
| C | 1980 | M |
| D | 1980 | M |
| E | 1980 | M |
| F | 1980 | M |
| G | 1980 | F |
| H | 1980 | F |
| I | 1980 | F |
| J | 1980 | F |
| K | 1980 | F |
| L | 1980 | F |
| M | 1981 | M |
| N | 1981 | M |
| O | 1981 | F |
| P | 1981 | F |
| Q | 1981 | M |
| R | 1981 | M |
| S | 1981 | F |
| T | 1981 | F |
| U | 1981 | M |
| V | 1981 | M |
| W | 1981 | F |
| X | 1981 | F |
| Y | 1982 | M |
| Z | 1982 | M |

**Output : Team 1**

| Name | Birth year | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1980 | M |
| D | 1980 | M |
| G | 1980 | F |
| H | 1980 | F |
| M | 1981 | M |
| N | 1981 | M |
| O | 1981 | F |
| P | 1981 | F |
| Y | 1982 | M |

**Output : Team 2**

| Name | Birth year | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1980 | M |
| E | 1980 | M |
| I | 1980 | F |
| J | 1980 | F |
| Q | 1981 | M |
| R | 1981 | M |
| S | 1981 | F |
| T | 1981 | F |
| Z | 1982 | M |

**Output : Team 3**

| Name | Birth year | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 1980 | M |
| F | 1980 | M |
| K | 1980 | F |
| L | 1980 | F |
| U | 1981 | M |
| V | 1981 | M |
| W | 1981 | F |
| X | 1981 | F |

Comment: It's going to be easy to understand if you add example of input outputs.

Comment: This sounds very much like homework. If it is, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), and even if it isn't, please show your efforts so far.

Comment: It's not homework, i'm developing a personal project but i struggle with this algorithm. Maybe I'd say sort by gender first and then by age and cyclically split the already sorted members into groups? That seems very inefficient and not too precise either. Maybe create a data structure for each group that stores the number of people for each gender of each age? Thanks

Comment: Get two data sets separated by gender. For each data pool, group the people by year of birth. For each gender based pool start picking people from one of those year based groups as long as the balance can be kept, then proceed with the next group. Repeat this task. Depending on the data one might not be able of staffing teams of reasonable size.

Comment: @user7913 ... Maybe the OP does the work of providing the raw data as array of data items ... `[{ name: 'A', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'female' }, { name: 'B', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'male' }/*, { ... }, ...*/]`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Depending on your data what you want could be impossible
2. If your data allows it you can
   a-Sort by date of birth and age clusters
   b-For each group : take a person in each cluster until the group is big enough

Comment: There are only 3 different years of birth, and only 2 different genders, how do you arrive at 200 clusters?

Comment: The example has been added after my post. updated my text. 200 or 300 are the absolute maximum

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment ...

> *"Get two data sets separated by gender. For each data pool, group the people by year of birth. For each gender based pool start picking people from one of those year based groups as long as the balance can be kept, then proceed with the next group. Repeat this task. Depending on the data one might not be able of staffing teams of reasonable size."*

Methods used ...

- [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for all grouping tasks which are grouping by gender, and within each gender group, grouping by year of birth. The target structure will look like this ...

  ```
  {
    "groupedData": {
      "M": {
        "1980": [{
          "name": "A",
          "yearOfBirth": 1980,
          "gender": "M",
        }, {
          "name": "B",
          "yearOfBirth": 1980,
          "gender": "M",
        }, {
          /* more like that */
        }],
        "1981": [{
          /* more like that */
        }],
        "1982": [{
          /* more like that */
        }],
      },
      "F": {
        "1980": [{
          "name": "G",
          "yearOfBirth": 1980,
          "gender": "F",
        }, {
          "name": "H",
          "yearOfBirth": 1980,
          "gender": "F",
        }, {
          /* more like that */
        }],
        "1981": [{
          /* more like that */
        }],
      },
    },
  }
  ```
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for transforming the object-only year-structure into an array based one. The `entries` of the male-group year-items are as follows ...

  ```
  [[
    "1980",
    [{
      "name": "A",
      "yearOfBirth": 1980,
      "gender": "M"
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "yearOfBirth": 1980,
      "gender": "M"
    }, {
      /* more like that */
    }]
  ], [
    "1981",
    [{
      "name": "M",
      "yearOfBirth": 1981,
      "gender": "M"
    }, {
      "name": "N",
      "yearOfBirth": 1981,
      "gender": "M"
    }, {
      /* more like that */
    }]
  ], [
    "1982",
    [{
      "name": "Y",
      "yearOfBirth": 1982,
      "gender": "M"
    }, {
      "name": "Z",
      "yearOfBirth": 1982,
      "gender": "M"
    }]
  ]]
  ```
- [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating an array like a list of all items with same year of birth.
- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to generically create the base structure of the list of teams by the provided amount of teams ... which for e.g. a team count of `3` needs to be ... `[[], [], []]`.

```js
function shuffleArray(arr) {
  // Fisher–Yates shuffle :: The modern algorithm
  // [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm]
  let idx;
  let count = arr.length;

  while (--count) {
    idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (count + 1));

    // Wiki-Quote: "The Fisher–Yates shuffle, as implemented
    // by Durstenfeld, is an in-place shuffle."
    [arr[idx], arr[count]] = [arr[count], arr[idx]];
  }
  // return mutated array.
  return arr;
}

function createBalancedTeams(data, teamCount) {
  return Object
    // get male based data entries.
    .entries(data['M'])
    // build `listOfTeams` which is the return value.
    .reduce((listOfTeams, [year, maleYearList]) => {

      // access male based year list as well.
      let femaleYearList = data['F'][year];
      if (
        // procceed only if there is a
        // viable amount of data available.
        (maleYearList.length >= teamCount) &&
        (femaleYearList.length >= teamCount)
      ) {
        // create shallow copies of year based lists
        // and set their items at random order.
        maleYearList = shuffleArray([...maleYearList]);
        femaleYearList = shuffleArray([...femaleYearList]);

        // compute the amount of items which can be spread
        // amongst the teams in a meaningful/valid way.
        let lowestEntryCount =
          Math.min(maleYearList.length, femaleYearList.length);
        lowestEntryCount =
          Math.floor(lowestEntryCount / teamCount) * teamCount;

        // limit the reference array's amount of items
        // to the just compouted above value.
        maleYearList.length = lowestEntryCount;
        // ... which is not necessary for the other array.
        // femaleYearList.length = lowestEntryCount;

        // process each item of the reference array ...
        maleYearList.forEach((maleItem, idx) => {
          // ... make sure to distribute
          // into the correct team ...
          const teamIdx = idx % teamCount;

          // ... and push both year based items into it.
          listOfTeams[teamIdx].push(
            maleItem,
            femaleYearList[idx],
          );
        });
      }
      return listOfTeams;

    }, Array.from({ length: teamCount }).map(() => []));
}

function groupItemByGenderAndYear(index, item) {
  const { gender, yearOfBirth: year } = item;

  const genderGroup = (index[gender] ??= {});
  const yearList = (genderGroup[year] ??= []);

  yearList.push(item);
  
  return index;
}

const sampleData = [
  { name: 'A', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'B', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'C', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'D', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'E', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'F', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'G', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'H', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'I', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'J', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'K', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'L', yearOfBirth: 1980, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'M', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'N', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'O', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'P', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'Q', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'R', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'S', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'T', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'U', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'V', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'W', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'X', yearOfBirth: 1981, gender: 'F' },
  { name: 'Y', yearOfBirth: 1982, gender: 'M' },
  { name: 'Z', yearOfBirth: 1982, gender: 'M' },
];

const groupedData = sampleData
  .sort((a, b) => a.yearOfBirth - b.yearOfBirth)
  .reduce(groupItemByGenderAndYear, {})

console.log({ groupedData });
console.log(
  'createBalancedTeams(groupedData, 3) ...',
  createBalancedTeams(groupedData, 3)
);

console.log(
  'createBalancedTeams(groupedData, 5) ...',
  createBalancedTeams(groupedData, 5)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @user7913 ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Comment: @user7913 ... are there any questions left regarding the above approach?